# Invalid principal in bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to learn how to develop web applications using AWS and following this workshop [Build a Modern Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-one/)
I have to update the s3 bucket policy, so as per the instructions in section B, I replaced the string `REPLACE_ME_BUCKET_NAME` in the JSON file with the bucket name that I created `mythicalbucket1` and this is the error I get:

> An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Invalid principal in policy.

This is the JSON file:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity REPLACE_ME_CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_ACCESS_IDENTITY_ID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mythicalbucket1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried reading the documentation for bucket policies and since I have to give access to the public (or everyone), I replaced the value for `Principal` as `*` which again gives a different error.

Looking at the JSON file, I'm assuming `REPLACE_ME_CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_ACCESS_IDENTITY_ID` has to be replaced with some CloudFront ID but not sure if that is needed in this case.

I did go through the various documentations about the CloudFront ID and bucket policies but everything is still confusing. Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the files provided with that workshop reference the use of Amazon CloudFront. However, the instructions do not mention it.

Therefore, you should simply use: `"Principal": "*"`

Also, please note that there should be a `/*` at the end of this line:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REPLACE_ME_BUCKET_NAME/*"
```

Make sure there is still a `/*` after your bucket name.

Comment: That worked ! Thanks a lot @John. I didn't know I had to include "/*" earlier, that's the reason "Principal":"*" didn't work.

Comment: The reason for the `/*` is that it grants `GetObject` permissions for the _contents_ of the bucket, rather than for the bucket itself.